# Is it possible to inject a service into a child component?

Tags: angular

I have a situation where I find myself replicating logic in parent components to fetch data from a server to populate a dropdown (this also includes handling pagination and search). I would therefore like to move this logic to the dropdown component where I can define it once.

However, this requires me defining which service the dropdown component should be using to fetch it's data. I would like to define this when I define the dropdown component in the parent.

**For Example**

```
<dropdown [service]="myService"></dropdown>
```

I could then call this function on the dropdown component passing parameters such as pagination and search parameters.

```
this.service(x,y,z).subscribe()
```

Is this possible?

I am also open to any other suggestions especially if I am looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: what version of angular are you using? as a rule of thumb the answer is no to you question about injecting a service as an attribute... but all angular services are available to components via dependency injection. Could  you show more of your code?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You could do something like this ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-specification-as-input)):

1- Define an `@Input()` property in the `DropDownComponent` receiving the service (I created an interface in this case for better design, `Logger`).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  template: `Dropdown using {{this.logger.getName()}}`
})
export class DropDownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public logger: Logger;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`DropDown, I'm using `, this.logger.getName());
  }
}
```

2- In the component that uses the drop down then define the value for the `logger` property.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <dropdown [logger]="this.logger1Service" ></dropdown>
  <br />
  <dropdown [logger]="this.logger2Service" ></dropdown>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public logger1Service: Logger1Service,
    public logger2Service: Logger2Service
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Hello from AppComponent');
    console.log('calling logger1Service.info() with message X', this.logger1Service.info('X'));
    console.log('calling logger2Service.info() with message Y', this.logger1Service.info('Y'));
  }
}
```

3- And define the services that could be provided for this dropdown.

```
// logger.interface
export interface Logger {
  info(text: string);
  getName();
}
```

---

```
// logger1.service
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { Logger } from './logger.interface';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Logger1Service implements Logger {

  constructor() { }

  info(text: string) {
    console.log('Logger 1:', text);
  }

  getName() {
    return 'Logger1Service';
  }
}
```

---

```
// logger2.service
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { Logger } from './logger.interface';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Logger2Service implements Logger {

  constructor() { }

  info(text: string) {
    console.log('Logger 2:', text);
  }

  getName() {
    return 'Logger2Service';
  }
}
```

Comment: lealceldeiro, this is what I was looking for in my project. I need service that connects list, pagination, sorting (and other) components. The same set of functions with different data and some implementations based on page it's used on. 
This is great. 
Question 1: Should Logger be service (instead of interface)?
Q 2: I think in HTML template (...[logger]="this.logger1Service"...) you should loose THIS. (it's minor issue)

Comment: @FilipWitkowski Great you found this useful :) regarding your questions: **1**: it depends on your design, as an interface it defines only a behavior to implement by actual service implementations, if it's a service then it should implement a specific behavior, maybe a default one in case there are not other providers. I always try to keep the design as clean as possible. What would be the goal to make it a service when there are other classes that implement it and are actually services? It's up to yo to decide that, but I would go for it as an interface and create specific implementations

Comment: @FilipWitkowski **2**: yes, you're right -- I missed that.... anyways, this a particular case asked by the OP, but this should not be the rule.... services are intended to be used through dependency injection (by declaring their dependencies through constructor arguments) -- that's a good practice that should be kept in mind

Answer (score 0):

It's better to wrap this dumb component into container and reuse it. You smart component will inject service with specific interface. The service you can declare in the parent component to container.

I created [stack blitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kh4rmz)

Comment: Thank you this seems like a smart approach to the problem. I have a question however about multiple dropdowns on the same page. If you were to create a specific interface but then needed to define multiple dropdowns each targeting different services. How would you tackle this?

Comment: In such case you can simply pass observable with request via input to drop down component.
The stream itself you have to declare in parent component

Comment: But with this approach it is not possible to modify the parameters of the observable request from the child? For example - `getBooks(page, searchTerm)`. Sorry if i am misunderstanding

Comment: Why do you need to modify it from child?
Child component should be dumb and has only presentation logic.
It will help you to keep low coupling between components.
You can provide parameters via inputs to child component and pass them to `getBooks` method.

Maybe I don't get the whole idea)
Can you provide me with more context? Why do you need to modify it from child?